# Find exact word mysql 8.0

Tags: mysql, uwp

I would like to find the exact word with a mysql query, in mysql 5.7 is equivalent to:

```
"SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE columnName RLIKE '[[:<:]]wordToFind[[:>:]]'"
```

while in mysql 8.0 it is:

```
"SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE columnName RLIKE('[^\\w]wordToFind[^\\w]')"
```

But this mysql 8.0 query I tested it in command prompt and it works but, in the UWP project it does not work because it also reads the records where there is not the exact word I'm looking for: with the beginning or the end different.

Some idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: my guess (and this is just a guess), the SQL text passed to MySQL doesn't contain the two consecutive backslash characters, and what is getting sent to MySQL is single backslash character e.g. `'[^\w]foo[^\w]'`. And that's because the backslashes are getting swallowed before the SQL is sent to MySQL. Analogous to specifying `"C:\\temp"` to get `"C:\temp"`... (just a guess.) I'd suggest outputting/logging the actual SQL text that is being sent to MySQL. Maybe we need to specify `[^\\\\w]`in order to evaluate to `[^\\w]`.

Comment: I tried but also selects the records with other words..

Comment: If the query "works" at MySQL command line client, but returns different results from the application (against the same database), that strongly suggests that the SQL being executed isn't the same. Again, I recommend outputting or logging the actual text of the SQL that is being sent to MySQL from the application.(In some of my bash scripts, to get a single backslash sent to MySQL, I have to encode that as *four* backslash characters because the SQL string gets evaluated *two* times before it's sent to MySQL. If it's not backslashes being swallowed, obviously something else is different.

Comment: It works perfectly… Really thank you!